# How to import a Sharepoint document library into Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I need to import a document library created in Sharepoint 2010 into Visual Studio 2010 to be able to deploy it as a part of the final solution. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can export a document library easily by going to the library settings and choose  "Save document library as template". This template then is easily imported to Visual Studio 2010.

What you can also do though is to export your whole Site as a site definition which you then can import to Visual Studio and probably extract your document library. Here is some sample code and a video:

[Importing SharePoint 2010 Site Definitions in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg512104.aspx)